# jQuery.fn in Plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert some code from jQuery to plain JavaScript. I've been unable to figure it out thus far. Here's the code:

```
// Website
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-dismissible]').dismissible();
});

// Plugin
(function() {

  jQuery.fn.dismissible = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var _this = jQuery(this);
      jQuery('[data-dismissible-hide]', this).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return _this.dismiss(options);
      })
    });
  };

  return jQuery.fn.dismiss = function(options) {
    // Ajax call...
  };

})();
```

Basically every DOM element in the page that matches "[data-dismissible]" is searched for child DOM element(s) that matches "[data-dismissible-hide]" where a "click" event is attached.

Comment: This might be useful: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing complicated about this example. You just replace `$` with `querySelector`, `.click` with `addEventListener` and `JQuery.fn` with `Type.prototype` and a few tweaks here and there.

```
// Add dismissible prototype to all elements
HTMLElement.prototype.dismissible = function (options) {
    this.querySelector("[data-dismissible-hide]").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.dismiss(options);
    })
};

// Add "dismiss" prototype to all elements
HTMLElement.prototype.dismiss = function (options) {
    // Ajax Call
}

// Abstraction to be able to call dismissible() on entire nodelists
NodeList.prototype.dismissible = function (options) {
    this.forEach(el=>{
        el.dimissible(options)
    })
}

// The actual call
document.querySelectorAll("[data-dismissible]").dismissible();
```